# Referencing Multiple Forms Using Name

Tags: javascript, forms, indexing, reference

I want to convert some of my index references to name references.

When I have only one form, I change this:

```
function checkFields(){
  if(document.forms[0].newcustsuffix.value == ""){
  ..... }
  .....
  <form action="UpdateCustNumber.jsp" onSubmit="return checkFields()">
```

to this:

```
function checkFields(){
  if(document.forms["SuffixForm"].newEmail.value == ""){
  ..... }
  .....
  <form action="UpdateCustNumber.jsp" name="SuffixForm" onSubmit="return checkFields()">
```

And that works fine. The issue I am having is when `document.forms.length` is larger than 1 and it has reference with numbers other than `0`. Example:

`document.forms[1].elements[0].value`

How would I access this one using a `name` reference?

**EDIT:**

When I run `document.forms.length`, it returns a length of 3.
To access those three elements I can use (different method)

```
document.forms[0].elements[0].value //""
document.forms[1].elements[0].value //B
document.forms[2].elements[0].value //G
```

If I use a name reference, it return only the last index.

```
document.forms["SuffixForm"].elements[0].value //G
```

Is there a way to access the first two indexes? I am fairly new in all of this so it is possible my basics are incorrect.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you mean that the `document.forms[1]` does not have a `name` attribute? if it does, why don't you get the form based on that name attribute?

Comment: @smarber Edited

Comment: If you want to catch your forms based on their names, you should not care anymore about the indexes or the order. All you have to do is retrieving by form name `document.form[<name_of_the_form]`.

Comment: @smarber So I should be fine just using `document.forms[<'name'>].method` to get the correct var?